# Checking tick boxes from data from database

Tags: php, sql, database, checkbox

***Sorry I should of explained this better. I tried to make it simple. What this form does is bring up a persons details and then the user can select, using the tick boxes, whether that person can have certain things (like rest breaks). So when the form is loaded the tick boxes are already ticked for the certain things... If that made sense. If a person was already entitled to rest breaks. and I load their details up on the form. The box for rest breaks should already be ticked.***

The student id is for the form to display the person that has been selected on the form. Also the status is corresponding to the request. it is either awaiting approval, approved or rejected.

```
                $selected_arrangement_query = "
            SELECT tbl_arrangement_id, arrangement, ta.status
            FROM tbl_arrangement AS ta
            WHERE 
            tbl_student_id = $selected
```

I'll keep this question short. What is going on is that I have a form with tick boxes on. Once the user clicks the text box it will post the data to the database and then show on the form as that option has been selected. But the the tick from the text box disappears. I want to make it so that once the data has been submitted the tick will remain there. There are about 40 boxes so I am expecting the coding to be long for all the different permutations but if someone can help me get started I can replicate it further.

Here is the start of it. The first few hidden values are just there to get the same user so it.

```
        <table>
        <form name='counter' id='counter' method="get"  >
            <tr><th colspan="8">Counter arrangements</th></tr>  
            <input type="hidden" name="selected" value="<?php echo $selected; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="edited" value="1" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="evidenceCount" value="<?php echo $selected_evidence_Total; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="arrangementCount" value="<?php echo $selected_arrangement_Total; ?>" />  

            <td valign="top"  >
              <input type="checkbox" Name='arrangements[]'  value='Rest Breaks' OnChange='this.form.submit();'>Rest Breaks</option>
            </td>           
            <td valign="top"  >
              <input type="checkbox" Name='arrangements[]' value='Small Classroom Environment' OnChange='this.form.submit();'>Small Classroom Environment</option>
            </td>
            <td valign="top"  >
              <input type="checkbox" Name='arrangements[]' value='Coloured Overlay' OnChange='this.form.submit();'>Coloured Overlay</option>
            </td>
```

UPDATE

Here is the code for the drop down boxes for approved rejected etc.

```
 <?php
    //declare counter
    $rowcount = 0;
    while ($row = $selected_arrangement_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf("<tr>");
        printf("<td><input type='hidden' name='arrangementRowID%s' value='%s' />",$rowcount,$row['tbl_arrangement_id']);
        printf("%s</td>",$row['arrangement']);
        if($row['status']=='Awaiting Approval'){
        ?>


        <td class="right">
        <select name='astatus<?php echo $rowcount; ?>' onchange='submitForm()'>
            <option value='Awaiting Approval' selected="selected">Awaiting Approval</option>
            <option value='Approved'>Approved</option>
            <option value='Rejected'>Rejected</option>
            <option value='Rejected-No Evidence'>Rejected-No Evidence</option>
            <option value='Approved on Appeal'>Approved on Appeal</option>
            <option value='Approved Alternative' >Approved Alternative</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <?php
        }elseif($row['status']=='Approved'){
        ?>
        <td class="right">
        <select name='astatus<?php echo $rowcount; ?>' onchange='submitForm()'>
            <option value='Awaiting Approval'>Awaiting Approval</option>
            <option value='Approved' selected="selected">Approved</option>
            <option value='Rejected'>Rejected</option>
            <option value='Rejected-No Evidence'>Rejected-No Evidence</option>
            <option value='Approved on Appeal'>Approved on Appeal</option>
            <option value='Approved Alternative' >Approved Alternative</option>
        </select>
        </td>
```

After more research I have found more code. I have amended it to fit my needs, will something like this work?
I know i will need to include all of the check boxes once I am done. I also will need an if statement for each but I want to get the first one working first.

```
         $arrangement = mysql_query("SELECT tbl_arrangement_id, arrangement FROM tbl_arrangement WHERE Id=$selected");
          $row = mysql_fetch_row($arrangement);
          $selected = explode(',', $row[$arrangement]);
          $j=0;
          for($i=0; $i<count($arrangement); $i++){
             if($j<count($selected) && $selected[$j] == $arrangements[$i]){
                echo $arrangements[$i]." <input type='checkbox' name='arrangements[]' value='". $arrangement[$i] ."' checked> ";
                $j++;
             }
            else echo $arrangements[$i]." <input type='checkbox' name='arrangements[]' value='". $arrangement[$i] ."'> ";
          }
```

Comment: Well basically on the load of your page, get the values that got ticked and make sure they are selected?!

Comment: You need some knowledge of JavaScript bro ;)

Comment: For several reasons, you should consider having the user submit the form and then process it.

Comment: @Naruto yea that's what i need help with!

Comment: @DDeme tell me about it bro, I am fairly useless at Javascript

Comment: @DanBracuk due to the use of the page it is easier for the user to be without a submit button

Comment: In that case, you had better have code for unchecking boxes as well.

Answer (score 0):

While going through the DB query result, you can save the info used for the checkboxes in an associative array with the value of the checkbox as the key.

**Update:**

If I understood your explanation correctly, you can implement it here:

```
<?php
  //declare counter
  $arrangements = [];
  $rowcount = 0;

  while ($row = $selected_arrangement_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $arr = str_replace(' ', '', $row["arrangement"]); // Removes spaces
    $arrangements[$arr]] = true;

    printf("<tr>");
    printf("<td><input type='hidden' name='arrangementRowID%s' value='%s' />",$rowcount,$row['tbl_arrangement_id']);
    printf("%s</td>",$row['arrangement']);
    // ...
```

Then in the checkboxes you can `echo` `selected="selected"` if the box value is found in the associative array:

```
<input type="checkbox" Name='arrangements[]'  value='RestBreaks' <?php echo isset($arrangements["RestBreaks"]) ? 'checked="checked"' : ""; ?> OnChange='this.form.submit();'>Rest Breaks</input>
```

Spaces in associative arrays might not work all too well, so the space in the value of the `input` have been removed in the above example.

Comment: Ok so i need to do that for each box? Thank you for your response

Comment: For each box yes, with the corresponding values.

Comment: So it works for when the clicks onto it. Sorry I should of explained this better. I tried to make it simple. What this form does is bring up a persons details and then the user can select, using the tick boxes, whether that person can have certain things (like rest breaks). So when the form is loaded the tick boxes are already ticked for the certain things... If that made sense. If a person was already entitled to rest breaks. and I load their details up on the form. The box for rest breaks should already be ticked.

Comment: So let's see if I understood you correctly. The page displays the information of a person, with checkboxes for these things they can have? Where does the information come from and how? A database I assume.

Comment: Ok, the principle is still the same, except instead of playing with GET variables, you need to make use of the data from the database. Show your table structure and/or an example of how you're getting the data from the DB and I can update my answer.

Comment: There is another form where a person will input their details and request things. This page has a list of the people and displays the information for them. The user grants them use of these things or can give them other things as an alternative. Hope that helps

Comment: Would an existing query be ok?

Comment: In `tbl_arrangement`, is `arrangement` the same info as in the form? As in the rest breaks and whatnot?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I should be more informative. From the input page the 'arrangements' are stored in the database along with the student ID. So the person can choose from rest breaks etc and they are stored in tbl_arrangement under arrangement column.

Comment: Ok edited the answer. If you're still having problems with the database loop part, show an example of how you're doing it now.

Comment: Its not working. It is probably due to my incompetence with PHP. could you give a full example? Thanks

Comment: You're giving very little to go on. You're obviously managing your database queries just fine if you're getting the student data to the page, so you just need to expand on those. If you give a full example of how you're handling the data from `tbl_arrangement`, I can help you forward.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to be as informative as I can. I don't understand what you are asking for. PHP and sql isn't my strongest.

Comment: I edited the question and I hope that gives you a better undertanding